# Where are CloudWatch log data stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Is there some document available that shows how AWS CloudWatch log data is stored at AWS?

Especially, I would like to know:

1. Is an existing service (e.g. Amazon S3) used for the storage of events?
2. Is there any encryption available?

Interestingly, information is available for CloudTrail, but there seems to be no documentation about CloudWatch.

Comment: +1 for noting that [CloudTrail encryption is available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/encrypting-cloudtrail-log-files-with-aws-kms.html) and CloudWatch doesn't...

Answer (score 5):

Logs is apparently sitting on top of Kinesis, so:

1. Yes, existing service, probably custom configured on AWS end
2. I think they handle this on their side

Based on this:
https://youtu.be/pTzv-i1uvvE?t=1386

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to configure to store in S3 and make sure that retention is enabled even after 90 days
2. Yes server side encryption is available
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html

Comment: From CW logs you can export to S3. It does not store in S3 by default.